# Examples of certain types of toposes

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

I'm looking for examples of (non-degenerate) categories $\mathcal{C}$ such that both $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{C}^{op}$ are toposes (assuming that such categories even exist).

On a related note, I'm looking for examples of (non-degenerate) categories $\mathcal{C}$ such that $\mathcal{C}$ is a topos and $\mathcal{C} \simeq \mathcal{C}^{op}$ (again, assuming that such categories even exist).

EDIT: I'm also looking for examples of (non-degenerate) categories $\mathcal{C}$ such that $\mathcal{C}^{op}$ is a topos.

Thanks!

Comment: What does "non-degenerate" mean, especially in the context of the last question? If $C$ is a topos, when is $C^{op}$ "non-degenerate"?

Comment: I realize 'non-degenerate' is kind of vague. By 'non-degenerate' I basically mean a category that has more structure than the terminal category 1, which satisfies my second question since 1 is a topos and is equivalent to its opposite.

Comment: Okay, so for your last question, just take the opposite category of an interesting topos. Do you want to require anything else of $C$?

Comment: One example I have in mind concerns the category Sets of sets and functions and the category CABA of complete atomic Boolean algebras. We know that Sets is a topos and CABA is the dual of Sets. Do we have other examples of toposes whose duals are still interesting mathematical categories (and I realize that 'interesting' is again somewhat vague)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $C^{op}$ is a topos then $(-) \sqcup X$ preserves all limits for any object $X$, and in particular if $1$ denotes the terminal object then $1 \sqcup X = 1$. It follows that

$$\text{Hom}(1, Y) \times \text{Hom}(X, Y) \cong \text{Hom}(1, Y)$$

and hence that if $\text{Hom}(1, Y)$ is non-empty then $\text{Hom}(X, Y)$ contains a unique morphism for every $X$; equivalently, $Y$ is terminal.

If $C$ is a topos then it has a subobject classifier $\Omega$, and taking $Y = \Omega$ above we know that $\text{Hom}(1, \Omega)$ is non-empty since $1$ has at least one subobject, namely itself. It follows that $\Omega$ is terminal, so every object $X$ has exactly one subobject.

But every object a priori has at least two subobjects, namely itself and the initial object. So now it follows that every object is the initial object, and hence $C$ is contractible (equivalent to the terminal category).