# In a CCC with the initial object, can I have a morphism A -> 0?

Tags: category-theory

I'm in a cartesian-closed category with the initial object $0$. What are the consequences of having a morphism from some object $A$ to $0$? Does it mean that there is also a global element of $0$, that is $1\to 0$ ?  Does it mean that we have a zero object, $1 \cong 0$ ? Does it mean that all objects are isomorphic?

Assume we don't have coproducts.

Comment: Initial objects in cartesian closed categories are strict, i.e. every morphism to an initial object is an isomorphism. If there is a morphism $1 \to 0$ then the category is trivial.

Comment: Is this a different question from the one we settled on twitter? I can't remember :)

Comment: I don't think we settled this question on Twitter, that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: @ZhenLin : Is there a simple proof of that?

Comment: @Bartosz: this is *exactly* the statement that is proven in my answer.

Comment: In nLab, there is a list of categories with strict initial objects and there's no mention of CCC. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/strict+initial+object

Comment: That list is not exhaustive (of course), and at any rate every CCC with coproducts is distributive.

Comment: @ZhenLin : I know that. My question was specifically about CCC's _without_ coproducts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the asker is not satisfied with Qiaochu's answer I'll try to expand on it and show more of the intermediate steps.

First we show that $X \times 0 \cong 0$, by showing that $X \times 0$ is an initial object.
$$Hom(X \times 0, A) \cong Hom(0, A^X) \implies |Hom(X \times 0, A)| = 1$$

This means that the projection $\pi_0: X \times 0 \to 0$ is an isomorphism. We use the $Hom(A, -)$ functor to get the isomorphism (functors send isomorphisms to isomorphisms).
$$Hom(A, \pi_0) : Hom(A, X \times 0) \to Hom(A, 0)$$
which is just post-composition by $\pi_0$.

The universal property of the product gives us another isomorphism, which we'll call $f$:
$$ f: Hom(A, X)\times Hom(A,0) \to Hom(A, X \times 0) $$

We can compose these two isomorphisms to get a third isomorphism:
$$ Hom(A, \pi_0) \circ f : Hom(A, X)\times Hom(A,0) \to Hom(A, 0)$$

It turns out that $ Hom(A, \pi_0) \circ f = \pi_{Hom(A,0)} $. This is because
$$ (Hom(A, \pi_0) \circ f)(g,h) = \pi_0 \circ f(g,h) = h $$

The last equality is due to the universal property of $A \times 0$. Hence the projection:
$$ \pi_{Hom(A,0)}:  Hom(A, X)\times Hom(A,0) \to Hom(A, 0)$$
is an isomorphism. If $Hom(A, 0)$ is non-empty then $Hom(A, X)$ also has to be non-empty. If $Hom(A, X)$ had more than one element then $ \pi_{Hom(A,0)} $ would not be injective which means $ Hom(A, X)$ has exactly one element and $A$ is an initial object.

Comment: I think, in your last sentence, you're making the same mistake as Qiaochu. If the second set is infinite, it can be isomorphic to double itself. See my counterexample.

Comment: Yes I agree that a set can be isomorphic to double itself: $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}$. The problem is that in my proof I'm saying that the projection map is an isomorphism (a stronger statement than saying the two sets are isomorphic). The projection $\pi : \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ is not an isomorphism. Since your counterexample is not a projection it is not valid. More generally, I am saying if a projection $\pi : A \times B \to B$ is an isomorphism then either $|A| = 1$ or $|B| = 0$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see it. The universal property of $A \times 0$ says that there is a bijection between pairs $(h_1 \colon A \to A, h_2 \colon A \to 0)$ and $h \colon A \to A \times 0$. The projection $\pi_0 \colon A \times 0 \to 0$ is a unique isomorphism because $A \times 0$ is initial. We have the commuting condition $\pi_0 \circ h = h_2$. What you are saying is that $h2 = h$. Can you prove it?

Comment: I'm not saying $h_2 = h$. Let $f$ be the bijection $h = f(h_1, h_2)$. This makes the commuting condition $\pi_0 \circ f(h_1, h_2) = h_2$. This means $\pi_0 \circ f = \pi_{Hom(A,0)}$ since they both map $(h_1, h_2) \to h_2$. Since $\pi_0$ and $f$ are isomorphisms so is their composition which means $\pi_{Hom(A,0)}$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: I wish we could draw the diagrams here. As I see it, if you draw the universal diagram for  $A \to A \times 0$, you can't squeeze more information out of it besides the commuting condition. If you draw the diagram for $A \to X \times 0$, you get a totally different $f$. If $X$ is different from $A$ then $X \times 0$ is different from $A \times 0$. Sure, they are isomorphic, but that doesn't mean they are equal.

Comment: I think maybe you are confusing the $A$ and the $X$ from my answer. The $X$ is an arbitrary element of the category. The $A$ is the element that has a morphism to $0$. I never take $A \times 0$ - I only take $X \times 0$. Both $\pi_0$ and $f$ are due to the $X \times 0$ product. This is why we can use the commuting property: $\pi_0 \circ f (h_1, h_2) = h_2$. Where $h_1: A \to X, h_2: A \to 0$ and $f(h_1, h_2): A \to X \times 0$. My proof for why $\pi_{Hom(A,0)}$ has two parts. (1) $\pi_0 \circ f = \pi_{Hom(A,0)}$ (commuting condition). (2) $\pi_0 \circ f$ is an isomorphism. What don't you buy?

Comment: I'll list the facts that we agree on: 
$$h = f(h_1, h_2)$$
 is an isomorphism, 
$\pi_0$ is an isomorphism between $X \times 0$ and $0$, 
$$\pi_0 \circ h = h_2$$
$$(\pi_0 \circ f)(h_1, h_2) = h_2$$ 
(although this doesn't add any more information). 
$$Hom(A, X) \times Hom(A, 0) \cong Hom(A, X\times 0)$$
which just restates the fact that $f$ is an iso.

The fact that $\pi_0$ is an isomorphism means that $Hom(A, X) \cong Hom(A, 0)$. What I don't understand is how you conclude from that that $Hom(A, X)$ is a singleton.

Comment: Do you also agree that the projection $(h_1, h_2) \mapsto h_2$ is an isomorphism (I call this projection  $\pi_{Hom(A,0)}$)? This is because $\pi_0$ and $f$ are isomorphisms and the projection is just their composition. Since this projection is an isomorphism it is also injective. The only way for it to be injective and for $Hom(A,0)$ to be non-empty is for $Hom(A,X)$ to be a singleton.

Comment: Tell me if I'm wrong in this counter-example. Let's number all the morphisms: $h_1$ is from the set $\{0, 1\}$ and both $h$ and $h_2$ are $\mathbb{N}$. I'm going to explicitly define:
$$f (h_1, h_2) = h_1 + 2 h_2$$
and its inverse
$$f^{-1}(h) = (h \text{mod} 2, h / 2)$$
where the division runds down to the nearest natural. 
$$\pi_0 \circ h = h$$
is obviously an isomorphism. I think this satisfies all the conditions.

Comment: It's not valid because $\pi_0 \circ f(h_1, h_2) = h_2$ and in your example it equals $h$. Also it's not clear to me what is meant by $\pi_0 \circ h$ since $h$ is a natural number.

Comment: Sorry for being sloppy. First of all, the $\pi_0$ is a morphism and $f$ is a function, so they don't compose. The correct equation is
$$(\pi_0 \circ -) \circ f = h_1$$
It's a post-composition by $\pi_0$ applied to the result of $f$. Second of all, What I meant by the numbering system is that you use naturals to number the morphisms. So, for instance, you pick $h_1$ from the set $h_1^0, h_1^1, h_1^2, ..., h_1^k, ...$, and $h$ from $h^0, h^1, ...$. I picked $\pi_0$ to be identity so, when postcomposed after $h^0$ it produces $h_2^0$, after $h^k$ it produces $h_2^k$. Sry for the confusion.

Comment: If $\pi_0$ is the identity then wouldn't $(\pi_0 \circ -) \circ f = f$? That would mean that it isn't a projection: $\pi_0 \circ f(h_1, h2) = f(h_1, h_2) = h_1 + 2h_2 \neq h_1$.

Comment: You're right, my bad! The action of $\pi_0$ should be $(\pi_0 \circ -) h = h/2$, just like in $f^{-1}$. Than the triangle commutes. Also, correcting the typo:
$$(\pi_0 \circ -) \circ f = h_2$$

Comment: In that case $(\pi_0 \circ -) \circ f$ is not an isomorphism since $(0, h_2)$ and $(1, h_2)$ both get sent to $h_2$. So this is not a counter-example.

Comment: Okay, I get it now. Here's how I understand it: Suppose that there are two morphisms $A\to X$, $h_1$ and $h_1'$. Pick any morphism $h_2 \colon A \to 0$. Universal construction maps the two pairs to two _different_ morphisms $h, h' \colon A \to X \times 0$. The commuting condition says that both $h$ and $h'$ postcomposed with $\pi_0$ must give $h_2$. But that contradicts the fact tha $\pi_0 \colon X\times 0 \to 0$ is the unique isomorphism between two terminal objects.

Answer (score 7):

In any cartesian closed category, product $X \times (-)$ distributes over colimits, and in particular over the initial object, so we have $X \times 0 = 0$. If $A$ is any object it follows that

$$\text{Hom}(A, X) \times \text{Hom}(A, 0) \cong \text{Hom}(A, 0)$$

in the sense that the projection map from the LHS to the RHS is an isomorphism, hence that if $\text{Hom}(A, 0)$ is non-empty then $\text{Hom}(A, X) = 1$ for all $X$, so $A = 0$. (Here I am using "equality" to mean that there is a unique map in one direction or another and that unique map is an isomorphism.)

**Edit:** In more detail, since this was apparently confusing. By $X \times 0 = 0$ I mean that the unique map $0 \to X \times 0$ is an isomorphism. Since this implies $X \times 0$ is the initial object, there is also a unique map $X \times 0 \to 0$, which must be the projection $\pi_0$, and which must be an isomorphism. Now we have the general observation that in any category with finite products, if

$$\pi_Q : P \times Q \to Q$$

is the projection then the induced map

$$\text{Hom}(R, P \times Q) \cong \text{Hom}(R, P) \times \text{Hom}(R, Q) \to \text{Hom}(R, Q)$$

is the projection $\pi_{\text{Hom}(R, Q)}$. So, from the fact that the projection $\pi_0: X \times 0 \to 0$ is an isomorphism, we deduce that for any pair of objects $A, X$ the projection

$$\pi_{\text{Hom}(A, 0)} : \text{Hom}(A, X) \times \text{Hom}(A, 0) \to \text{Hom}(A, 0)$$

is an isomorphism. If $\text{Hom}(A, 0)$ is empty then both sides are empty and we don't learn anything. But if $\text{Hom}(A, 0)$ is non-empty, or equivalently if $A$ admits a morphism to $0$, then the fibers of this map can all be identified with $\text{Hom}(A, X)$, so it follows that if $\text{Hom}(A, 0)$ is non-empty then $\text{Hom}(A, X) = 1$ for all $X$, so $A = 0$.

I had forgotten this argument but apparently I knew it [in 2015](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1217933/examples-of-certain-types-of-toposes/1218006#1218006), although in that answer I wrote it in the opposite category. (We don't use the full strength of the assumption of cartesian closure, only that finite products exist and distribute over initial objects, so this argument continues to work in a [distributive category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/distributive+category).)

If $A = 1$, or more generally if $A$ has a global point, it follows that the category has a zero object, and now the isomorphisms

$$\text{Hom}(X, Y) \cong \text{Hom}(1, Y^X) \cong \text{Hom}(0, Y^X) \cong 1$$

show that there is a unique morphism between any pair of objects, so the category is contractible.

Comment: I'm stuck at the step when you claim that $Hom(A, X)$ must be a singleton. $Hom(A, 0)$ could be an infinite set.

Comment: @Bartosz: again, the claim is not just that the LHS and RHS are isomorphic but that the projection map is an isomorphism. The fibers of the projection map are each a copy of $\text{Hom}(A, X)$ (as long as $\text{Hom}(A, 0)$ is non-empty), so in order for it to be an isomorphism each of the fibers must be a point.

Comment: I don't understand. This is in fact an isomorphism: $Hom(A, X) \times Hom(A, 0) \cong Hom (A, X \times 0)$, but it doesn't prove that $Hom(A, X)$ is a singleton.

Comment: @Bartosz: yes it does. Here is the general fact stated precisely: let $P, Q$ be sets and let $\pi_Q : P \times Q \to Q$ be the natural projection. If $Q$ is non-empty, then every fiber $\pi^{-1}(q)$ is in bijection with $P$, and hence $\pi_Q$ is a bijection iff $P$ consists of one element.

Comment: Here's a counter-example. Let $P$ be the set $\{0, 1\}$ and $Q$ be the set of natural numbers. The mapping $(b, n) \to 2 n + b$ is a bijection, where $b \in P$ and $n \in Q$.

Comment: @Bartosz: I do not know how to explain this more clearly than I have already explained it. I am not referring to an arbitrary bijection. I am referring to the natural projection $\pi_Q(p, q) = q$, and to this map *only*. I have said this three times already. Your map is some other map which has nothing to do with $\pi_Q$.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you _assuming_ that the projection must be an isomorphism? Projections usually aren't, so where does it come from? In my counter-example, both $(0, n)$ and $(1, n)$ are projected to $n$.

Comment: @Bartosz: this is exactly the content of the argument. Since products distribute over finite coproducts we have $X \times 0 = 0$ in the sense that the unique map $0 \to X \times 0$ is an isomorphism. Since this implies $X \times 0$ is the initial object, there is also a unique map $X \times 0 \to 0$, which must be the projection $\pi_0$. Now verify that if $\pi_Q : P \times Q \to Q$ is the projection then the induced map $\text{Hom}(R, P \times Q) \cong \text{Hom}(R, P) \times \text{Hom}(R, Q) \to \text{Hom}(R, Q)$ is the projection $\pi_{\text{Hom}(R, Q)}$.

Comment: I've edited further details clarifying the argument into the answer. The point is exactly that the argument shows that the projection is an isomorphism which implies that its fibers must be points.

Comment: I have no problem with $X \times 0 \cong 0$, but how does this lead to the conclusion that $\pi_Q$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: @Bartosz: this is exactly addressed in the next step of the argument: if $\pi_Q : P \times Q \to Q$ is the natural projection, then applying the functor $\text{Hom}(R, -)$ produces a map $\text{Hom}(R, \pi_Q) : \text{Hom}(R, P) \times \text{Hom}(R, Q) \to \text{Hom}(R, Q)$. This map is exactly the projection $\pi_{\text{Hom}(R, Q)}$, so if $\pi_Q$ is an isomorphism then so is $\pi_{\text{Hom}(R, Q)}$. Now take $Q = 0$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118302/discussion-between-bartosz-milewski-and-qiaochu-yuan).

Comment: I've added an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4877251/501886) with a drastic simplification of this argument that does not involve Hom functors at all.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simpler version of Qiaochu's argument that does not mention $\mathrm{Hom}$ functors: let $0$ be initial and $f : A \to 0$. Since the category is cartesian closed, products distribute over colimits and so $0 \times A$ is initial.

We will exhibit $f$ as an inverse to the unique morphism $\mathop{!} : 0 \to A$. We clearly have $f \circ \mathop{!} = \mathrm{id}_0$, so it suffices to check that $\mathop{!} \circ f = \mathrm{id}_A$:

[image: commutative diagram]

The right triangle commutes by initiality of $0 \times A$. Thus $A$ is also initial.

Comment: More conceptually, an isomorphism $X\cong X\times Y$ means that in any span $X\leftarrow W\to Y$, $W\to Y$ factors as $W\to X\cong X\times Y\to Y$. In particular, $X\cong X\times Y\to Y$ is a retraction of any morphism $X\leftarrow Y$. But if $X$ is initial, then $X\cong X\times Y\to Y$ is also a section of any morphism $X\leftarrow Y$, hence an isomorphism. Similarly, if $X\times Y$ has no non-identity idempotents (e.g. if it is initial), then there is at most one morphism $X\to Y$, at most one morphism $Y\to X$, and the two are inverses to one another if both exist.